# UITableViewでカスタムCellを使用した時に表示が重なる

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

InterfaceBuilderを使用しないでカスタムCellを使用したTableViewを作成しています。

`ViewController`で`UITableView`を追加して
`CustomCell`クラスを作成し、その`ContentView`に`CustomView`クラスを追加しています。

`ViewController`で

```
[_tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

を使用して起動すると
１つのセルに複数のセルがかぶって表示されます

`ViewController.m`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    return cell;
}
```

`CustomCell.m`

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

        if (self) {
            for (UIView *subview in [self.contentView subviews]) {
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
            }

            _dateLabel  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 0, 320 - (16 * 2), 20)];
            _dateLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
            _dateLabel.text = [[NSDate date] description];
            [self.contentView addSubview:self.dateLabel];

            // ここのビューがスクロール時に２重に表示されることがある
            CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0, 20, 160, 20);
            _view1 = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
            [self.contentView addSubview:_view1];

            CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(160, 20, 160, 20);
            // その他ViewをaddSubView
        }
        return self;
    }
```

`CustomView.m`

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
            [self initializeView:frame];
        }
        return self;
    }
    -(void)initializeView:(CGRect)frame
    {
        for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }

        _titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(44 + 16, 0, 160 - 44, 22);
        _titleLabel.text = @"text";
        [self addSubview:_titleLabel];

        _conditionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _conditionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(44 + 16, 22 + 4, 160 - 44, 22);
        _conditionLabel.text = @"text2";
        [self addSubview:_conditionLabel];
    }
```

原因は`cellForRowAtIndexPath`で@"Cell"のIDでセルを再使用しているため起こる原因と思いますが、
`registerClass`でIDを固定しているため、複数のIDで再使用をしないということができません。
カスタムCellを使用して、そのCellに`addView`した状態で表示が重ならない方法はありますか?

[image: こんな状態で表示されます]

Comment: スクリーンショットを貼ってもらわないと、どういう状況か把握できません。よろしく。

Comment: スクリーンショットをUPしました

Comment: configureCell:メソッドも載せてもらったほうがいいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

スクリーンショットを拝見させていただいた範囲で判断できるのは、テーブルの行の高さと、ひとつひとつのセルの高さが一致していないという点です。テーブルの行の高さは、セルのサイズにあわせて、自動で調節されるわけではないという点を、ご留意ください（※）。
テーブルの行の高さは、`UITableView`のプロパティ`rowHeight`で調節します。セルが重ならないようにするには、すくなくとも現状の2.7倍にはしないといけなさそうです。
なお、行間をひとつずつ異なる値にするには、`UITableViewDataSource`プロトコルの、`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`メソッドを使います。

※Auto Layoutを利用して、セルのサイズに合わせて、行間を自動調節する手法は、あるらしい。